# Curly brackets for sequencing arguments in Dockerfile's COPY

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So ... I wonder how to use curly brackets syntax in the `COPY` command within `Dockerfile`

I'm looking for something equivalent to `bash`'s

```
$ cp /path/file.{ext1,ext2,ext3} ./
```

so I tried:

```
COPY ./Cargo.{toml,lock} ./
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `COPY Cargo.toml cargo.lock  /app/` or use `COPY Cargo.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#copy), you can only use Go’s [filepath.Match](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath#Match) rules. So you'll either have to use a wildcard (e.g., `./Cargo.*`), or list them out explicitly (e.g., `./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.lock`).